# OS X - How can create only one window using segue and preserve data?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have two `View Controllers`. First one have `sendbutton` that segue to second view controller. `Action Segue` is `Show`. Each time click the button, new window pops up again. I don't want create new window again, and I just want to only one second `View Controller`.

And my `FirstViewController.m` :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(NSStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender{
        SecondViewController *destinationScene = [segue destinationController];
        destinationScene.receivedString = _nextOne.stringValue;
}
```

`SecondViewController.m` :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear{
        if(_myMutableArray == nil)  _myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        [_myMutableArray addObject:_receivedString];
}
```

What I want to is send a string in the first `View Controller`'s `TextField` repeatedly to next `View Controller`. And keep using only one second window that created at first time.

[See my Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvuPY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set up the segue to happen automatically.  Create an IBAction for the button, test whether your second view controller is already on the screen, and either segue or not depending on whether it already exists.

Comment: I might solve the problem with your idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in IB without any code. Update the Presentation attribute for the view controller in the destination view from Multiple to Single:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36104388/287963