# How do I only allow one instance of a window in Xcode (Swift)?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I'm designing a preferences window and I want it to act similarly to the ones on OS X's default programs - only one preferences window can be open at a time, and any attempts to open another one redirect the focus to the current prefs. window.

I realise I could make it modal but I want to know the best ways to handle a problem like this.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard in your project?

Comment: It'll take just one bool variable and a window-close notification to achieve that goal.

Comment: If you are using storyboards, see [OS X storyboards: using “show” segue without allowing duplicate new windows to show?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096257/os-x-storyboards-using-show-segue-without-allowing-duplicate-new-windows-to-s/36104388#36104388)